# Take substring of string using regex in sql

Tags: sql, regex

I want to take substring of a string in sql by using regex.

To elaborate; I have a string in a column like;

```
user_type-admin;group-ezd;city_dc-antalya;distributor_name-Stok'is Gıda;
dm-serdar Cöm;advisor_dm-serdar Cöm
```

This string includes some variables names and values separated by '`-`' and '`;`'.

I want to update this column to substring of this string that does not include `city_dc,dm, and advisor_dm` and their values (e.g. antalya,serdar cöm and serdar cöm).

For each word I want to write an regex and update column. So, 3 updates are okey but, I don't want to write hundreds of updates beacuse of variety of values.(Values can change but variable names are fixed.)

So after 3 updates my column value be;

```
user_type-admin;group-ezd;distributor_name-Stok'is Gıda
```

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Which [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) are you using?